# A polynomial formula for the primes

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers

Is there a proof that there is no polynomial which would return $n$th prime for the input value $n$?

In other words is there an explanation for why there is no polynomial $P(x)$ such that $P(n)=p_n$ for every natural number $n$ and $p_n$ being the $n$th prime and the coefficients of the polynomial being taken from some field.

Comment: That would be amazing! Joke apart, as $n\to\infty$, the polynomial will grow with rate $x^m$, $m$ being the degree of the polynomial but the number of primes grows much slower than this.

Comment: I am aware of that idea but is there an explanation that doesn't make a reference to the asymptotics of the prime distribution.

Comment: Not that I am aware off. Btw, my $x$ was supposed to be an $n$ in my above comment.

Comment: Would [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Prime_formulas_and_polynomial_functions) answer you question ?

Comment: No because this presupposes the coefficients of the polynomial are integers but I'm also interested in the case where they can be rational, real, complex etc.

Comment: The first constraint is to have a polynom $P$ so that at least $\forall n \,,\, P(n) \in \mathbb{N}$. From [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial#Classification), we know exactly from which elements $P$ can be made of. Using such a decomposition, you might be able to use the argument given in the link of Lucian...

Answer (score 3):

Let $F$ be a field which contains the rationals, and let $P$ be a non-constant polynomial with coefficients in $F$ such that $P(n)$ takes on prime values for infinitely many positive integers $n$. We show that $P(n)$ also takes on non-prime values.

For suppose that $P$ is prime for infinitely many positive $n$, and has degree $m\ge 1$. The coefficients of $P$ are rational. For suppose $P(a_i)=b_i$, where the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are rational,  for $m+1$ distinct  $a_i$. By Lagrange interpolation, there is a polynomial $P^\ast$ with rational coefficients and degree $\le m$ such that $P^\ast(a_i)=P(a_i)$ at our $m+1$ distinct $a_i$. But then by uniqueness $P=P^\ast$.

There is an integer $L\ge 1$ such that all the coefficients of $P$ have shape $\frac{p_i}{L}$, where the $p_i$ are integers.   Then $P(x)=\frac{Q(x)}{L}$ where $Q(x)$ has integer coefficients.

Suppose that $P(n_0)=p$. Then $Q(n_0)=Lp$. For any $k$, we have $Q(n_0+Lpk)$ is divisible by $Lp$. So $P(n_0+Lpk)$ is an integer divisible by $p$. It follows that for any large enough $k$, the number $P(n_0+Lpk)$ cannot be prime.

Answer (score 0):

Say $p(x)$ does as you want. Then $p(0) = q$, a prime. But each term of $p(q x)$ is divisible by $q$, and so $q$ divides $p(q x)$, which is a prime. Thus $p(q x) = q$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, contradiction.

Comment: The OP stated in the comments that they didn't want to assume the coeffcients of $p$ were integers.